# Difference between Gini Importance vs Mutual Information

Tags: regression, machine-learning, feature-selection, importance

I am tackling a regression problem. I have used XGBoost as my model and implemented `feature_importances_`, which by default scores the importance of a feature using Gini importance.

I have also done some feature selection to reduce the number of features and see how it affects the RMSE score. This is done using `SelectKBest` and using a scoring metric of **mutual information**.

I want to generally ask what is the difference between Gini importance and mutual information?